# Redux - How to add item into certain property

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm really struggling with this, I want to add a new item to the "binnacleNotes" property in my "binnacleNotesReducer", I have tried several approaches that I found on the internet with not good results.

Either the new note gets added into the main property "binnaceNotesReducer" or is not added.

I have the following redux structure:

[image]

Please refer to my several attempts in code below:

```
case ADD_NEW_NOTE:
      const { id, date, binnacle_note, responsibleState, attachments, constructor_review, super_review, dro_review, timestamp } = payload;
      const newNote = {
        binnacleNotes: {
          id,
          date,
          binnacle_note,
          responsibleState,
          attachments,
          constructor_review,
          super_review,
          dro_review,
          timestamp,
        },
      };
      //return state.binnacleNotes.concat(newNote);
      return {
        ...state.binnacleNotes,
        binnacleNotes: {
          ...state.binnacleNotes,
          id,
          date,
          binnacle_note,
          responsibleState,
          attachments,
          constructor_review,
          super_review,
          dro_review,
          timestamp,
        },
      };
```

Different approach:

```
   case ADD_NEW_NOTE:
      const { id, date, binnacle_note, responsibleState, attachments, constructor_review, super_review, dro_review, timestamp } = payload;
      const newNote = {
        binnacleNotes: {
          id,
          date,
          binnacle_note,
          responsibleState,
          attachments,
          constructor_review,
          super_review,
          dro_review,
          timestamp,
        }
      }
      return state.binnacleNotes.concat(newNote);
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading more docs, i found the solution, hope this helps anyone:

```
case ADD_NEW_NOTE:
      const { id, date, binnacle_note, responsible, attachments, constructor_review, super_review, dro_review, timestamp } = payload;
      return {
        binnacleNotes: [
          ...state.binnacleNotes,
          { id, date, binnacle_note, responsible, attachments, constructor_review, super_review, dro_review, timestamp },
        ],
      };
```

Comment: It looks like the payload is the note?  So there’s no point to destructuring.  Also if there are any properties other than binnacleNotes I your reducer then you need to copy them.  I’m assuming there aren’t here, but it’s something to keep in mind.  return { ...state, binnacleNotes: [ ...state.binnacleNotes, action.payload ] }

Comment: Yep, you're right, sorry for the delay. What about if I only need to update certain property and not add a new item to the ocject? I've been struggling with that.